# Issue with shutil move when path is unknown

Tags: python, shutil

So I have files saved in multiple subdirecties, I want to move all files with certain extensions to a new directory. This is what I have:

```
path = 'C:/Users/R/Documents/16-2/gsi_14-01-2019'
dest_path = 'C:/Users/R/Documents/Hyperspectral/Datafiles/Raw'

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.raw' in file:
            shutil.move((path + '/' + file), (dest_path + '/' + file))
```

This is throwing this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/R/Documents/16-2/gsi_14-01-2019/16-2_132_564m65_569m00_2019-01-11_12-30-56.raw'
```

because the file is in a subdirectory of the path, I think?. First part is able to find the file, but I need to feed to feed the full (originally unknown, determined) path to the shutil move function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: On windows, you should use backslashes "\" instead of "/" as path separator.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to move a file to another file. What you need to do is move the file to a directory. Does it work if you just use shutil.move((path + '/' + file), dest_path)

Comment: No I tried using just dest_path and it throws the same error

Comment: The source will be `os.path.join(r, file)`. This is a common FAQ with `os.walk`.